# Overwriting the uploaded files with same name in ui-component forms

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, file-upload

I have a UI-component form for admin which has a field to upload image/file. The file uploading is working all right, after saving the form the name of the image is saved in the database. 
The issue comes when I upload an image with such a name which is used by another previous record, then the file gets updated for both the records.

I want to know, how **Magento** makes these names unique?

Answer (score 1):

Yes magento making the namespace unique.  like

**First time upload**

```
marker.png
```

**Second time upload**

```
marker-1.png
```

**Second time upload**

```
marker-2.png
```

You can check it in your `pub/media/youruploadfolder`

Answer (score 0):

In magento2, you can upload files using `Magento\Framework\File\Uploader` class.

```
/** @var Magento\Framework\File\Uploader $fileUploader */

/** If this method is set to TRUE, uploaded file name will be changed if some file with the same name already exists in the destination directory (if enabled). */

$fileUploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
```

and then finally

```
/* Used to save uploaded file into destination folder with original or new file name (if specified)*/

$fileUploader->save($destinationFolder, $newFileName = null);
```